# MouseLeftButtonUp is not triggered on the RadGridView Rows

Tags: silverlight, radgridview, mouseleftbuttonup

I am using telerik RadGridView to show datas. And I want to achieve double click the row and open it. I achieved this on DataGrid before with MouseLeftButtonUp event. But in RadGridView it is not triggered on the rows area, but triggered except the rows.

I have searched this for a long, but did not get the similar situation. Below is my XAML code:

```
<telerik:RadGridView x:Name="rgvSystemUser" ItemsSource="{Binding SystemUsers}" IsReadOnly="True"
                         AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                         CanUserSelect="True" SelectionUnit="FullRow">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonUp">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding GridDoubleClickCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=gridSystemUser,Path=SelectedItem}"></i:InvokeCommandAction>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding UserName}" Header="UserName" IsGroupable="False" Width="1*"></telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding TECLevel}" Header="TEC Level" Width="1*" ></telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding UserRole}" Header="Role" Width="1*" ></telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding UserNotes}" Header="Notes" IsGroupable="False" Width="2*" ></telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
        </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
    </telerik:RadGridView>
```

who knows why? And help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the mouseLeftbuttonup with, this will execute the command on double click or on keyboard enter

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="RowActivated">
              <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=EditEventCommand}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```